# What word am I looking for (similar to "subset")

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

If...

- (A) is a subset of (A)
- (A,B) is a subset of (A,B,C)
- (B,A) is not a subset of (A,B,C) because order matters.
- (B,C) is not a subset of (A,B,C) because I only want to compare the front of each set.

Now *subset* is the second cousin of the word I'm actually looking for. ***Which word would best fit here?***

Maybe:

- *is a prefix of*
- *begins*

... but they seem awkward. Bonus points if there's a common term with an accepted Mathematical meaning (I'm not sure if some term exists).

Comment: Looks like you're not looking at sets or ordered tuples, but at subsequences of the string ABC..., which all begin with the first element of that string?

Comment: Subsequence! That's much much closer to what I'm getting at.

Comment: *Prefix* is the standard term for this, not awkward one little bit.

Comment: *Subsequence* is the standard term for another concept. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_%28computer_science%29) for more info.

Comment: What do you mean by "because I only want to look"?

Comment: @Jim To be honest, I don't know what I meant. I must have hit "Ask Question" before I completed that sentence. I've edited it to explain that the sets are ordered and I only want to compare the first elements of each.

Comment: I only hesitate to use prefix because those are more commonly applied to strings rather than sets. "AB" is a prefix of "ABC", but a tiny bit more awkward is "apple, orange" is a prefix of "apple, orange, pear"

Comment: It is not unusual at all to talk about [prefixes of sequences](https://www.google.com/search?q="prefix+of+*+sequence"). In fact a string is just a finite sequence of elements drawn from a finite set, called the alphabet. {apple, orange, pear} is a perfectly good alphabet as far as mathematics is concerned.

Comment: @MichaelJSwart But it looks like what you have here **is** a string.

Comment: @MichaelJSwart The correct term is prefix as n.m. pointed out. (A), (A,B), ... are not sets (at least not in your example); they are sequences. Sets are by definition unordered and cannot have a "front".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a branch of Math called [Formal Language Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language_theory).  The terminology of Formal Language Theory generally comes from everyday English, and terms like *prefixes*, *is a prefix of*, *begins (with)* and *starts (with)* are commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

It might be called *initial segment*.

References [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395604/is-there-any-specific-terminology-to-refer-to-an-initial-sequence-of-a-sequence) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464347/definition-of-initial-segment).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single word, but what about "ordered initial subset" or "initial subsequence"?

Answer (score 0):

You might try **preamble** or **truncated form**.

(A,B) is a preamble to (A,B,C,D)

(A,B) is a truncated form of (A,B,C,D)